# \arctan used to render correctly, but now doesn't

Tags: symbols, libre-office

Before I could write  \arctan x  and it rendered correctly.

But now I have to write  \text{arctan} x  to get this.

I must have lost a font?  How can I get it back to the way it used to work?

I'm using TexMaths in LibreOffice.

This suddenly happened, and I reinstalled LibreOffice with a newer version of TexMaths, but this problem remains.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Sorry, but LibreOffice doesn't use TeX. Its module for typing mathematics uses TeX syntax, but the implementation is completely different.

Comment: The TeXMaths applet used by LibreOffice only borrows TeX syntax, but implements it in a completely different way, so the present issue cannot be solved on the TeX side